# Restrict fields in Result

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am working with MongoDB v3.0.1 and the MongoDB Java Driver 3.0.0-RC1.

I have an user collection with fields like "username", "firstname", "lastname", "email", and so on.

Now I want to select all users but only with the fields "username", "firstname" and "lastname".

On the Mongo-Shell it is working with `db.user.find({}, { "username" : true , "firstname" : true , "lastname" : true})`

But how can I do it in Java? I tried it with 
`final BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("{}", new BasicDBObject("_id", true));
final MongoCursor<Document> usersCursor = col.find(query)`

For this I get an empty result back because it's translated as `{ "{}" : { "_id" : true , "firstname" : true , "lastname" : true}}`.

I also tried it with BasicDBList, but this isn't accepted by `col.find()`

With the "old" Mongo 2.x driver I would use `new BasicDBObject(BasicDBObject(), new BasicDBObject("username", true).append("firstname", true).append("lastname", true)`

Is there a possibility to do that or do I have to fetch all fields?

Greetings
Sören

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the new CRUD API in the 3.0.0 Java driver, the proper way to do it is with the projection method that is chained off off MongoCollection.find().  Since the projection method takes an instance of the Bson interface, there are a number of different classes you can use to specify the projection:

```
    // using BasicDBObject
    collection.find().projection(new BasicDBObject("username", true)
                                 .append("lastname", true)
                                 .append("firstname", true))

    // using the new Document class
    collection.find().projection(new Document("username", true)
                                 .append("lastname", true)
                                 .append("firstname", true));

    // Using the new Projections builder
    collection.find().projection(Projections.include("username", "lastname", "firstname"));
```

As for the way you say it works in the 2.x driver, that's not possible, as

```
new BasicDBObject(BasicDBObject(), BasicDBObject("username", true)
                                  .append("firstname", true)
                                  .append("lastname", true)
```

does not compile.  I'm not sure what exactly you were doing with 2.x, but the proper way to accomplish this with the DBCollection class in 2.x (which is still supported in the 3.0 driver), is:

```
    collection.find(new BasicDBObject(), new BasicDBObject("username", true)
                                        .append("lastname", true)
                                        .append("firstname", true));
```

Comment: Thank you for the possibilities and sorry for your confusion about my example. You are right that `BasicDBObject` wouldn't work. It was a typo mistake from me. I forgot a new in front of it. I fixed it in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the implementation of [**DBCollection**](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-) [**`find()`**](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.7.2/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject%29). The following returns the `"username"`, `"firstname"`, `"lastname"` and `"_id"` fields for every document in the collection that has an `"username"`, `"firstname"` and `"lastname"` fields:

```
BasicDBObject keys = new BasicDBObject();
keys.put("username", 1);
keys.put("firstname", 1);
keys.put("lastname", 1);
final MongoCursor<Document> usersCursor = col.find(new BasicDBObject(), keys);
```

Comment: Your solution is only possible if I use the [getDB()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/Mongo.html#getDB-java.lang.String-) method from the [MongoClient](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html) class. Is there a solution for the [getDatabase()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html#getDatabase-java.lang.String-) method?

Answer (score 2):

`collection
   .find(new Document(...).append(...))
   .projection(new Document(...).append(...))`

This will give you a `FindIterable` and then you can iterate through as you would `DBCursor`.