# How can I retrieve all the values in a column in mongo db into a ArrayList?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

This is the values of my data stored in mongo db. How am I able to retrieve all the data of "HomeTown" and store it all into a list? My list would contain AA, AA, BB, BB, etc... I want to use that array list to create a for loop of each Hometown.

**Sample mongo data**

```
 [{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ceb753a70fdf877ef5113ca"} , "HomeTown" : "AA" , 
"PhoneNumber" : { "CustName" : "xxx" , "Number" : "3403290"},
"MobileNumber" : { "CustName" : "yyy" , "Number" : "9323304302"}}]

    [{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ceb753a70fdf877ef5113ca"} , "HomeTown" : "AA" , 
"PhoneNumber" : { "CustName" : "xxx" , "Number" : "3403290"},
"MobileNumber" : { "CustName" : "yyy" , "Number" : "9323304302"}}]

    [{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ceb753a70fdf877ef5113ca"} , "HomeTown" : "BB" , 
"PhoneNumber" : { "CustName" : "xxx" , "Number" : "3403290"},
"MobileNumber" : { "CustName" : "yyy" , "Number" : "9323304302"}}]

    [{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ceb753a70fdf877ef5113ca"} , "HomeTown" : "BB" , 
"PhoneNumber" : { "CustName" : "xxx" , "Number" : "3403290"},
"MobileNumber" : { "CustName" : "yyy" , "Number" : "9323304302"}}]
```

How can I get all of the values of "HomeTown" in Java into an array? I am trying to create a for loop with the HomeTown Names. I am currently using mongodb dependency through Spring boot. I am not sure how would I implement mongodb into my java to use mongo db.

**Attempt/Problem**

I was able to retrieve mongodb values in a list using the following code. I am trying to convert this list to a arraylist.

```
public List<AppPortModel> getAppPortList() {
List<ApServerModel> objLst =  mongoOperations.findAll(ApServerModel.class);

String[] apServerArray = new String[objLst.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < objLst.size(); i++) {
            apServerArray[i] = objLst.get(i);
        }
```

**Error on objLst.get(i)**

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ApServerModel to String
```

**Attempt #2 Following Sagar Example**

```
        @Autowired
    MongoOperations mongoOperations;

MongoCollection<ApServerModel> myCollection =   **mongoOperations.getCollection("apAllCustomer");**

List<ApServerModel> result = myCollection.find().into(new ArrayList<>());
```

**Error on mongoOperations.getCollection**

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from DBCollection to MongoCollection<ApServerModel>
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Comment: Is that JSON format?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Those are data stored in mongo db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using mongo 3.x driver.You'll need to use something like this.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("mkoydb");
MongoCollection<Document> myCollection = db.getCollection("apAllCustomer");
List<Document> result = myCollection.find().into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Fix for Attempt 1:

```
public List<AppPortModel> getAppPortList() {
   List<ApServerModel> objLst =  mongoOperations.findAll(ApServerModel.class);
   String[] apServerArray = new String[objLst.size()];
   for(int i = 0; i < objLst.size(); i++) {
        apServerArray[i] = objLst.get(i).getHomeTown();
}
```

Fix for Attempt 2:

```
 DBCollection dbCollection = mongoOperations.findAll(AppServreModel.class, "apAllCustomer");
```

Comment: Would this script for mongodb work on cloud foundry? I uploaded a my spring app with some mongodb insertions and the application never loaded up.

Comment: It should try it out. It's not spring specific though.

Comment: I attempted your example but I receive some syntax errors. I posted error in my post.

Comment: You are mixing mongodb driver 3.x with 2.x. Added the spring variants for your use case.

Comment: Thank you! the Fix for my Attempt 1, solved it for me. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can call `toArray()` which, intuitively, returns a `List<DBObject>`.

```
  List<DBObject> myList = null;
        DBCursor myCursor=myCollection.find(new BasicDBObject(),"HomeTown");
        myList = myCursor.toArray();
```

if you are using java driver with version 3.0 and above you can also do

```
collection.find().projection(Projections.include("HomeTown"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*projection*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-projection) to retrieve only required fields.

```
db.apAllCustomer.find( ..., { HomeTown: 1 } );
```

In Java it depends on the API you use. See this for Spring Data:

> [SpringData MongoDB Using projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460155/springdata-mongodb-using-projection)

MongoDB-Java:

> [Restrict fields in Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332266/restrict-fields-in-result)